RPI5 Cannot connect to Wi-Fi (Association took too long)
Just new RPI5 model B rev. 1, just upgraded packages. RPI OS Lite.
nmcli r wifi on
nmcli d wifi rescan
nmcli d wiri list

shows all the existing WiFi stations perfectly. Hovewer
nmcli d wifi connect ESSID password PaSsWoRd

fails to connect with
Error: Connection activation failed: The Wi-Fi network could not be found.

From journalctl -u NetworkManager
May 14 21:33:32 pi NetworkManager[768]: <info>  [1715711612.6888] device (wlan0): Activation: starting connection 'Redmi_1CF0_5G' (94e12bed-0899-4072-a7eb-c8c9a5e74c4d)
May 14 21:33:32 pi NetworkManager[768]: <info>  [1715711612.6889] device (wlan0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
May 14 21:33:32 pi NetworkManager[768]: <info>  [1715711612.6891] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
May 14 21:33:32 pi NetworkManager[768]: <info>  [1715711612.6893] device (wlan0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
May 14 21:33:32 pi NetworkManager[768]: <info>  [1715711612.6895] device (wlan0): Activation: (wifi) access point 'Redmi_1CF0_5G' has security, but secrets are required.
May 14 21:33:32 pi NetworkManager[768]: <info>  [1715711612.6896] device (wlan0): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
May 14 21:33:32 pi NetworkManager[768]: <info>  [1715711612.6905] device (wlan0): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
May 14 21:33:32 pi NetworkManager[768]: <info>  [1715711612.6907] device (wlan0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
May 14 21:33:32 pi NetworkManager[768]: <info>  [1715711612.6909] device (wlan0): Activation: (wifi) connection 'Redmi_1CF0_5G' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
May 14 21:33:32 pi NetworkManager[768]: <info>  [1715711612.6910] Config: added 'ssid' value 'Redmi_1CF0_5G'
May 14 21:33:32 pi NetworkManager[768]: <info>  [1715711612.6910] Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
May 14 21:33:32 pi NetworkManager[768]: <info>  [1715711612.6910] Config: added 'bgscan' value 'simple:30:-70:86400'
May 14 21:33:32 pi NetworkManager[768]: <info>  [1715711612.6910] Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'SAE FT-SAE'
May 14 21:33:32 pi NetworkManager[768]: <info>  [1715711612.6910] Config: added 'psk' value '<hidden>'
May 14 21:33:32 pi NetworkManager[768]: <info>  [1715711612.6910] Config: added 'ieee80211w' value '2'
May 14 21:33:58 pi NetworkManager[768]: <warn>  [1715711638.4134] device (wlan0): Activation: (wifi) association took too long, failing activation
May 14 21:33:58 pi NetworkManager[768]: <info>  [1715711638.4135] device (wlan0): state change: config -> failed (reason 'ssid-not-found', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
May 14 21:33:58 pi NetworkManager[768]: <info>  [1715711638.4138] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
May 14 21:33:58 pi NetworkManager[768]: <warn>  [1715711638.4140] device (wlan0): Activation: failed for connection 'Redmi_1CF0_5G'
May 14 21:33:58 pi NetworkManager[768]: <info>  [1715711638.4142] device (wlan0): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')

/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile

[ifupdown]
managed=false

[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

I have tested it with three different routers and two phones on both 2.4GHz and 5GHz - problem persists.
Official power supply, problem persists with/without the case.
There is no problem with external Wi-Fi dongle, only with internal.
